# Using Total Commander and 7-zip-zstd, I cannot copy directly from a packed .7z file

Tags: windows-10, compression, 7-zip

I use Total Commander with https://github.com/mcmilk/7-Zip-zstd , I've got the plugins and the TotalCMD .dll's installed.

According to the github I should be able to decompress packed .7z files. But sometimes I don't need all the files from a packed .7z, so I just open the .7z, select a file and copy it. And that works fine if I use the official 7-zip. If I use this https://github.com/mcmilk/7-Zip-zstd it says:

[image]

I'm at loss what to do.

Comment: File an issue onto the developper's project page ?
This capability might simply be missing.